# beginner:referencing a cell containing a zero matlab

Tags: matlab, reference, cell

So far I have got this code:

```
    clear all; % clears all variables from your workspace
close all; % closes all figure windows
clc; % clears command window
%%=============================================
%%define number of trials and subjects
%%=============================================
njump=81;
nsbj=6;

%%
%%==============================================
%%defining size of cell that will be created
%%==============================================
data=cell(njump,1);

%%
%%==============================================
%%defining gravity and frame rate per second (fps)
%%==============================================
fps=0.001; %frames per second
g=-9.81; %acceleration

%% 
%%==============================================
%%read in excel data in CSV format
%%===============================================

for i=1:njump;
    x=sprintf('Trial%02d.csv',i),sprintf('Trial%02d',i),'A1:E7000';;% jump data
    data{i}=xlsread(x,'A1:E7000');


%%===============================================
%%defining total no. of frames and time of flight
%tnf=total number of frames equal to zero
%n = nnz(X) returns the number of nonzero elements in matrix X.
%%===============================================
%     myMax(i) = nanmax(data{i}(:,5));
%     vals = find(data{i}(:,5) > (myMax(i) - 10));
%     pointsInAir = numel(vals,i);
    tnf(i,1) = size(data{i,1},1) - nnz(data{i,1}(:,5)); %number of zeros
    tof(i)=tnf(i)*fps; %Time of flight is equal to this
    jh(i,1)=(-g*(tof(i).^2)/8); %defining jump height



%%=================================================
%%to find average power first use "find" function to find the first zero in
%%Fz, have the cell referenced
%%then use nanmean for average power(av_pwr)
%%use nanmin for peak power (peak_pwr)
%%=================================================

n = 1; % the following call to find retrieves only the n first element(s) found.
ref= find(data{i,1}(:,5)==0, n, 'first');
%   ref=find(data(:,5)==0); 
    peak_pwr(i,1) = nanmin (data {i,1}(1:ref,5)); %preak power in coloumn E1 in all data with reference to cell found
    av_pwr(i,1)=nanmean(data {i,1}(1:ref,5));%average power in coloumn E1 in all data with reference to cell found    

%%==================================================
%%Plot the results onto a time vs jump height, time vs average power and
%%time vs peak power
```

However the part that is hard is trying to find the first zero in column E which is the 5th column to use as a reference cell. I want to use this reference cell so that I can do my average and peak power calcs. that use the numbers before this zero.

Comment: Incorporate a tolerance into your `find` call to avoid [floating point errors](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/floating-point-numbers.html#bqxyrhp).

Comment: Either - (1) There is no zero value in that column or even if it appears to you that there might be a zero, but it's very close to zero and not exactly zero. OR (2) That column has strings and not numbers.

Comment: i think i might have imported it in as a string so how would I change the code for a string?

Comment: Don't put additional information in the comments, but rather edit your question. I tried to do this based on the comments but didn't get the formatting right so please do it yourself. -- Also it seems that your problem is not referencing at all, so you may want to use a better question title.

Comment: sorry! i will do it now

Answer (score 0):

In this case `ref` is empty so you cannot access the first element.

If you think that `ref` should not be empty you need to go back further to see where things go wrong. Otherwise, you can use something like:

```
if any(ref)
%Do something
else
%Return the default value/do alternative action
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It could help to have an example of what's in data. I have created one which might be similar to yours :

```
data{1,1}=magic(6)-10
```

Now in this matrix, column 5 actually does have a zero element so `ref= find(data{1,1}(:,5)==0); ref(1)` actually works and retrieves the first index of a zero element. However, if it didn't, you would be trying to access the first element of an empty matrix.

Try instead using the second (and perhaps third) arguments of find to achieve this :

```
n = 1;
% the following call to find retrieves only the n first element(s) found.
ref= find(data{1,1}(:,5)==0, n, 'first');
```

The rest of your code seems like it should work, although from the looks of it i have a feeling your loop (i take it you are using a loop for i) could maybe be vectorized.

Hope this helps :)

Tepp

Comment: sadly it didn't work either, just came back with the same error so I think I might have used a string. I have edited my question so it is more clear about my code!

Comment: Thanks for the edit of your code, the extra info does help :) I guess it now depends on what you want your code to do if there are no zero elements in that column ?

Comment: look at the part of the code you gave me now in my script, as i got the code you gave me to work for average power but now it is not using it for peak_power when this is the exactly the same data that needs to be

Comment: in fact, this works for me as long as i delete the space between data and the curly braces : `data{i,1}` instead of `data {i,1}`

Comment: and as a side note, unless you are using the data cell array for something else later in your code, you might want to consider changing data{i,1} with a data matrix instead which would be replaced at each new iteration. e.g. `data=xlsread(x,'A1:E7000');` and thereafter `ref=find(data(:,5)==0, 1, 'first');` etc. otherwise, you will be keeping in memory njump=81x[7000x5] matrices whereas, from what i understand, you only need one at any point in time.